# How do I hot reload a controller in Koa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

When a request comes in, I want to reload the controller to improve debugging speed.

When I make a change to a controller method I have to reload the whole server which take 4-5 seconds.

I am also using `koa-mount` to configure different endpoints so the solution must be compatible with `koa-mount`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it by patching `koa-mount`, allowing a string of the module path to be passed in, and having require being called on every request.

In dev mode, we invalidate the cached modules we want to reload.

In prod, the `require` call in our patched `koa-mount` will use the cached module.

See here: https://gist.github.com/vjpr/b13bd1bc2f636bb28cd8